Ошибка Attempt to call function 'has_method' in base 'null instance' on a null instance в Godot
Хочу, чтоб объект удалялся при взаимодействии. Он удаляется, но выскакивает ошибка.
Код взаимодействия:
var look_at_interact_object = null
func _physics_process(delta):
    look_at_interact_object = null
    if $Camera3D/RayCast3D.is_colliding():
        if $Camera3D/RayCast3D.get_collider().has_method("interact"):
            look_at_interact_object = $Camera3D/RayCast3D.get_collider()
    if Input.is_action_pressed("interact") and look_at_interact_object:
        look_at_interact_object.interact() 

Код объекта:
func interact():
    queue_free()


Попробуйте добавить проверку на null для collider перед вызовом has_method(). возможно это поможет избежать ошибки.
